# Integrating Separable Equations

Tags: calculus, integration

This is the problem and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get $x$'s and $y$'s on opposite ends of the equation:
$$-xy'-y=y^{-2}$$

Comment: $-xy' = y+y^{-2}$, so $\frac{y'}{y+y^{-2}} = -\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! So simple!